# Reading in a text file upto specific number of characters

Tags: java, text

::A Newbie here::

I've a text file having text like

**COM22: 15:55:09 20.09.2013VOLT=224**

I want to read this line and separate it to get

**15:55:09 20.09.2013**

and then

**Volt=224**

At this time I'am using br.readLine() which reads the whole line...Is there any way I can restrict br.readline() to start from certain numbered chracter (e.g. 4th character in line)and end on a certain(e.g. 8th)???

Comment: you didn't really tag this with the language you're using, but I'm assuming java ?

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry..Yes I'm using java..

Comment: Are you sure that there is no space between the date and VOLT part ?

Comment: theres a > between volt part and time part but I was not able to put it in my post..

Comment: @LeoLion Post an image. Maybe there are more details.

Comment: I was going to post an image when I asked this Question,but the site rule says that I should have a reputaion of 10 or more to post an image :/

Comment: @bsd originally the text is comming like this
<COM22: 15:55:09 20.09.2013>VOLT=224
What I'm trying to do is,separating both parts and then placing them in two separate columns...

will it help If I post what(code) I'm already using???

Comment: You could probably just read in the entire line to a `String` and use the `substring` method on the `String` to restrict it to the part that you want of that line.

Comment: Thanks people for helping me out.I appreciate every one helping a complete stranger like me...My Problem is solved now :) Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to restrict characters, read the whole line like

```
String line = br.readLine();
```

From the comments I see, you want to parse

```
<COM22: 15:55:09 20.09.2013>VOLT=224
```

Now split that into parts. The first part is

```
int leftAngleIdx = line.indexOf('<');
int rightAngleIdx = line.indexOf('>');

//Some error handling code if left >= right or if any of them were -1.


String comAndDate = line.substring(leftAngleIdx + 1, rightAngleIdx); //substring operates on half open intervals. 

//Similarly using substring operations. Extract the date part from comAndDate

String volt = line.substring(rightAngleIdx + 1); // After '>'
```

You could also use regex, perhaps later.

Comment: Thanks a lot bsd :) That was exactly what I wanted.Now my code works exactly as I want it to :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way for you to do this I think would be to use a regex (if you dont know what a regex is, read about it [here](http://www.regexbuddy.com/regex.html)). Here is a regex that might help for your general (because using magic numbers like 4 and 8 tends to be bad) -

```
^.*?\s([\d: \.]*)(.*$)
```

In this case capture group 1 would be `15:55:09 20.09.2013` and group 2 would be `Volt=224`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can restrict br.readline() to start from certain numbered character [etcetera]

No.

If you are going to use `BufferedReader.readLine()`, you will need to use a regex or something to split or parse the line into components.

Alternatively, you could use the `Scanner` class, and its `next...` methods to read the individual fields.